# What does navigator.gelocation accuracy relate to?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Using the navigator.geolocation object in JavaScript. Trying to establish accurate ranges, but wondering exactly how accurate they are.

navigator.geolocation has an accuracy value, but I don't know what they number relates to in real terms. Does the value have a real world equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [geolocation standard](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#accuracy) specified the accuracy as being in meters, and that it should correspond to a 95% confidence level.

So if you draw a circle with a radius of `accuracy` around the actual physical position, (at least) 19 out of 20 reported positions fall within that circle. In practice, this value allows you to roughly gauge the quality of positioning: If it is above 100, the positioning is only accurate to city level. If it is less than 10, the values are of high quality.

Comment: So when my phone was reporting 2k+, the only thing that was certain was that it was on Earth somewhere!

Comment: Not quite. 2000+ means a circle of 2km, which allows you to pinpoint the region or (large) city. That's enough for many applications; you only need `Find movie theaters in Glasgow`, not `Find movie theaters in 42 Oxford Street, Swindon`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be rude. Anonymized the example. 2000 means a circle of 2km. A value of 2000000 would be `anywhere on earth`.

Comment: So you are saying the number does have a real world equivalent. It relates to metres from a central point. The small the number, the closer to the centre its predicted accuracy.

Comment: The central point is the actual physical location, but other than that, yes. I tried to express that in the second sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the [W3C Editor's Draft](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#coordinates_interface):

"The accuracy attribute denotes the accuracy level of the latitude and longitude coordinates. It is specified in meters and must be supported by all implementations. The value of the accuracy attribute must be a non-negative real number.

The altitudeAccuracy attribute is specified in meters. If the implementation cannot provide altitude information, the value of this attribute must be null. Otherwise, the value of the altitudeAccuracy attribute must be a non-negative real number.

The accuracy and altitudeAccuracy values returned by an implementation should correspond to a 95% confidence level."

Also, per the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_geolocation):

"enableHighAccuracy – A boolean which indicates to the device that you wish to obtain it’s most accurate readings (this parameter may or may not make a difference, depending on your hardware)"